# Is it possible to select all rows from table 1 and each row meta data from table 2 in a single query?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm building a small CRM, I want to know if there's a way to actually bring all rows from table 1 but also in the same result, each row's meta data from table 2, let's say `tasks t2`.

Right now I'm using 2 queries, one to bring all rows from t1, then in a loop I select all rows from t2 if there's a match on the `t1_id` I push to the existing array the data.

```
t1
-------------------
id
number
created_at
updated_at


t2
-------------------
id
t1_id
something
created_at
updated_at
```

Comment: use join and ordered query to get all data from tables and in your application code transform your dataset

Answer (score 1):

This may solve you problem :

```
SELECT *  
FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
```

Comment: Here `order by t1.id` is important

Answer (score 1):

I think the best is to use a group_concat but there is other ways :

```
 SELECT t1.id,
  t1.number,
  t1.created_at,
  t1.updated_at
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISCTINCT t2.something) as meta
 FROM t1
 LEFT JOIN t2 on t1.id = t2.t1_id
 GROUP BY t1.id,
  t1.number,
  t1.created_at,
  t1.updated_at
```